# How to use rm interactively in a while read loop?

Tags: bash, rm

I'm little stuck in a script that's used to find and delete certain files. I want to give the user the opportunity to iterate through the list and delete each file only after human approval.

However, I find the script to skip the user interaction and don't delete.

```bash
cat $fileToBeDeleted | while read in; do

    rm -i "$in"
    echo "deleted: $in"

done;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of using `rm -i` you can use if statement to ask for confirmation before you delete the file. In this example I used a text file (to_delete_list.txt) that contains the list of files that I will be deleting.

`read -u 1 answer` will let you ask for user input in the loop.

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r file; do
  echo "do you want to delete $file (y/n)?"
  read -u 1 answer
  if [[ $answer = y ]]
  then
        rm $file
        echo "deleted: $file"
  else
        continue
  fi
done < "to_delete_list.txt"
```

Comment: This doesn't really solve how to deal with rm -i in a script, but your proposal actually solves my issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try a for loop with full path to `rm` for example:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in ./*
  do  /bin/rm -i "$i"
done
```